# I want to add icon from fontawesome

Tags: html, css

I want to add an icon but it doesn't show up in the web page, and yes I have downloaded 'fontawesome for the web'.

I've inspected the code and it say that the height and the width are `0x0` and I can't change it because "The `display: inline` property prevents `width` from having an effect. Try setting `display` to something other than `inline`."

```css
.container {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* Small */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
/* Medium */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
/* Large */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
/* End Global Rules */
header {
  padding: 20px;
}

header .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="container">
        <div>
          <img class="logo" src="/images/logo.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="Links">
          <span class="icon-bar">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-ba-staggered"></i>
          </span>
          <ul>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
</header>
```

I have tried to inspect the code and I didn't found anything except what I've said

Comment: How are you integrating the fontawesome library? Is there a `<script>` in your HTML head linking to your kit?

Comment: No, I download the library and i linked the all.min.css file, I've try to do it like every one, But it seems the problem from the files, I tried to link it from the web and it did work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest, and probably best, way to add any icon is as an svg element. You simply download the svg then paste in to your HTML. You can download fontawesome icons (top right on their webpage). Example:

```css
svg {
 height: 96px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.2.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. --><path d="M234.7 42.7L197 56.8c-3 1.1-5 4-5 7.2s2 6.1 5 7.2l37.7 14.1L248.8 123c1.1 3 4 5 7.2 5s6.1-2 7.2-5l14.1-37.7L315 71.2c3-1.1 5-4 5-7.2s-2-6.1-5-7.2L277.3 42.7 263.2 5c-1.1-3-4-5-7.2-5s-6.1 2-7.2 5L234.7 42.7zM46.1 395.4c-18.7 18.7-18.7 49.1 0 67.9l34.6 34.6c18.7 18.7 49.1 18.7 67.9 0L529.9 116.5c18.7-18.7 18.7-49.1 0-67.9L495.3 14.1c-18.7-18.7-49.1-18.7-67.9 0L46.1 395.4zM484.6 82.6l-105 105-23.3-23.3 105-105 23.3 23.3zM7.5 117.2C3 118.9 0 123.2 0 128s3 9.1 7.5 10.8L64 160l21.2 56.5c1.7 4.5 6 7.5 10.8 7.5s9.1-3 10.8-7.5L128 160l56.5-21.2c4.5-1.7 7.5-6 7.5-10.8s-3-9.1-7.5-10.8L128 96 106.8 39.5C105.1 35 100.8 32 96 32s-9.1 3-10.8 7.5L64 96 7.5 117.2zm352 256c-4.5 1.7-7.5 6-7.5 10.8s3 9.1 7.5 10.8L416 416l21.2 56.5c1.7 4.5 6 7.5 10.8 7.5s9.1-3 10.8-7.5L480 416l56.5-21.2c4.5-1.7 7.5-6 7.5-10.8s-3-9.1-7.5-10.8L480 352l-21.2-56.5c-1.7-4.5-6-7.5-10.8-7.5s-9.1 3-10.8 7.5L416 352l-56.5 21.2z"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no fontAwesome icon named as `fa-ba-staggered`

You might be looking for:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<i class="fa-solid fa-bars-staggered"></i>
```

You can search on [fontawesome.com/search](https://fontawesome.com/search) website for any icons that you need.

Ref: https://fontawesome.com/icons/bars-staggered?s=solid&f=classic

Comment: still there's no result

Comment: i've tried random icons and there's no result, hmm is that mean's there's somthing wrong with the version i've downloaded?

Comment: I've pasted into codepen and it shows using your HTML
https://codepen.io/microalps/pen/wvxybYW

Comment: yeah i see but why it doesn't show in my web page

Comment: @Abdalmalkkasem maybe you are not including the fontawesome assets as they tried to suggest you on comments. Here for example https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome or you should self host them

Comment: @MarcO.Alfonso I hope you don't mind if I put your code in a snippet to show the working result and to better highlight the correct asset linking

Comment: @MarcO.Alfonso Yes, it's problem with my files or code i will search for it, Thank u very much for help